# Disabling / Enabling nlog rules at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

I am using nlog with the `nlog.config` file.

Now I have a target that logs unhandled exceptions to a webservice

```
<target xsi:type="WebService" name="webservice"
    url="http://server.tld/services/errorreporting/"
    methodName=""
    namespace=""
    protocol="HttpPost"
>

....

</target>
```

And a rule:

```
<logger name="*" minlevel="Fatal" writeTo="webservice" />
```

Now I wan't to allow the user to decide if he wants to use this feature.
The application is a winforms app and the user sees a dialog for unhandled exceptions. Now I want to add an `errorreporting` checkbox. Only if it is checked, I want to log to my webservice.

My idea is to use a filter for my rule with a custom condition. The [nlog docs](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Conditions) claim:

`New condition functions are easy to add; just create an ordinary function and mark it with the [ConditionMethod] attribute.`

So I could write a function

```
public static bool ErrorReportingEnabled()
{
   return Properties.Settings.Default.ErrorReportingEnabled;
}
```

but I don't find any reference on how to define this function in my filter.

Comment: https://github.com/Emudofus/BehaviorIsManaged/blob/master/Librairies/NLog/Conditions/ConditionMethods.cs

Comment: Instead of reading the settings from your nlog config file I would try to change the logger rule at runtime, I hope [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302561/reconfiguring-nlog-programmatically) will give you some insight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I just changed my rule to

```
<logger name="WebServiceLogger" minlevel="Fatal" writeTo="webservice" />
```

and in my code I just create a logger with this name.