# NLog configuration changed programmatically saved back to config file

Tags: configuration, nlog

I have an application using NLog for logging. My configuration is stored in NLog.config file, but I need to provide option to change it for the user. I know how to change Logger configuration, but is it possible to save such changed configuration back to NLog.config file programmatically so it stays changed also after application stopped?

Thanks a lot!
Marek

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had more or else similar issue. I needed to edit the nlog config file. since i was using net2.0 , I was not able to use linq to edit the nlog config file . but edited the file using  xdocument.
hope the link below helps. 
[how to edit the nlog config file programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199507/how-to-edit-the-nlog-config-file-programmatically)

Answer (score -1):

You can follow the following [link](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-API) which gives a details about **Configuration API** which may help you.

Comment: Yeah I checked the documentation but there is no note about storing configuration back to config file.

Comment: Follow this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302561/reconfiguring-nlog-programmatically)