# Set logger max log level per HTTP request via filter

Tags: asp.net-core, nlog

I'm using NLog 4.7.5 with ASP NET Core 3.1, and would like to set the max log level per HTTP request. My idea is to set MappedDiagnosticsContext within a middleware layer, and apply a dynamic filter. I've done a quick test in LINQPad to demonstrate the filtering.

```
var appSettings = @"{
  ""NLog"": {
    ""throwConfigExceptions"": true,
    ""targets"": {
      ""logConsole"": {
        ""type"": ""Console"",
        ""layout"": ""${logger} | ${date} | ${level:uppercase=true} | ${message} | ${exception:format=tostring}""
      }
    },
    ""rules"": [
      {
        ""logger"": ""*"",
        ""minLevel"": ""Info"",
        ""writeTo"": ""logConsole""
      }
    ]
  }
}";

var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
builder.AddJsonStream(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(appSettings)));
var configuration = builder.Build();

MappedDiagnosticsContext.Set("MyLogLevel", LogLevel.Error);
var config = new NLogLoggingConfiguration(configuration.GetSection("NLog"));
config.LoggingRules.First().Filters.Add(
    new ConditionBasedFilter
    {
        // works
        Condition = "level < LogLevel.Error",

        // does not work
        //Condition = "(level < '${mdc:item=MyLogLevel}')",
        Action = FilterResult.Ignore
    });
var logFactory = new LogFactory(config);
var logger = logFactory.GetCurrentClassLogger();

logger.Info("Informating");
logger.Warn("Warning");
logger.Error("An error");
logger.Debug("Debugging");
logger.Trace("Tracing");
logger.Fatal("A fatal");
```

However running this, you can see the output from switching the filters around proves the MappedDiagnosticsContext doesn't work.

*Static filter*

[image: Static filter]

*Dynamic filter*

[image: Dynamic filter]

My configuration seems valid (no exceptions thrown), however why is this not working? Is there an alternative approach? I considered using a Dependecny Injecting LogFactory and named using loggers, but this approach seems the most straightforward.

Comment: Looks similar to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47517826/193178 With the difference that you are using `${mdc}` instead of `${environment}`

Comment: Also looks similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51754425/193178