# Why the LogLevel rule is not set for my NLog?

Tags: c#, .net-core, command-line-interface, nlog

I want to set the log level programmatically.
But when I look up my logs, all logs are written (from Trace to Error).
I code it like the example on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302561/reconfiguring-nlog-programmatically).

```
foreach (var rule in NLog.LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules)
{
    //rule.EnableLoggingForLevel(nlogLevel);
    rule.EnableLoggingForLevels(NLog.LogLevel.Warn, NLog.LogLevel.Fatal);
}
NLog.LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
Logger.LogTrace("LogLevel Trace");
Logger.LogDebug("LogLevel Debug");
Logger.LogInformation("LogLevel Info");
Logger.LogWarning("LogLevel Warn");
Logger.LogError("LogLevel Error");
```

I tried

```
rule.EnableLoggingForLevel(nlogLevel);
```

and

```
rule.EnableLoggingForLevels(NLog.LogLevel.Warn, NLog.LogLevel.Fatal);
```

Screen shot of the log's:
[image]

**Why I can't change the log level?**

Comment: have you tried to disable the others?

Comment: That's interesting, because rule.DisableLoggingForLevel(NLog.LogLevel.Trace); works. It was just not the way I wanted to go, but a good workaround.

Comment: maybe you have a nlog.config with all levels enabled?

Comment: @LorenzoIsidori Yes. But I thought whatever is written at my nlog.config I could set it programatically?!      <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="CentralLog" />

Comment: Of course you can but, at start, NLog load his config from file. if your config file has all level enabled, that will be your default...then you can go overriding levels. can you share your nlog.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct, enabling a loglevel doesn't mean disabling another.

Otherwise this will be an issue:

```
rule.EnableLoggingForLevel(LogLevel.Warn);
rule.EnableLoggingForLevel(LogLevel.Error); // luckily this won't disable Warn
```

What you could do:

Disable all loglevels first, and then enable the ones you need

```
rule.DisableLoggingForLevels(LogLevel.Trace, LogLevel.Fatal); // disable all
rule.EnableLoggingForLevels(NLog.LogLevel.Warn, NLog.LogLevel.Fatal); // enable needed
```

For this case - a minimum for all rules - there is also an easier way:

```
LogManager.GlobalThreshold = LogLevel.Info; // For all rules, minimum is Info
```

Please note that it's unclear why all the levels are enabled by default in your code. That's configured in the nlog.config or code, as that is not a default from NLog.

Comment: You can just call `SetLoggingLevels()` instead of calling `DisableLoggingForLevels()` and `EnableLoggingForLevels()`.

Comment: You're right. `SetLoggingLevels()` has been added in NLog 4.5

Answer (score 2):

This also happened to me and I was able to solve it by running `LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();` after changing log levels.

Answer (score 2):

This will work for your case:

```
rule.SetLoggingLevels(NLog.LogLevel.Warn, NLog.LogLevel.Fatal);
```

From documentation:

> Enables logging the levels between (included) minLevel and maxLevel. **All the other levels will be disabled**.

- https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.5.0/html/M_NLog_Config_LoggingRule_SetLoggingLevels.htm